# Amazon is <beloved/loved> by investors

Tags: passive-voice, participial-adjectives

Here's what Charlie Rose said in a segment of CBS's 60 minutes titled "[Amazon's Jeff Bezos looks to the future](http://www.cbsnews.com/news/amazons-jeff-bezos-looks-to-the-future/)":

> Bezos believes low costs ensure customer loyalty to Amazon, even if it's at the expense of profits. **Amazon** is one of the rare companies that on a quarterly basis shows little profit and yet **is beloved by investors**.

Is it also possible to use "loved" instead of "beloved" here?

Which is more natural in context? And Why?

Is there any difference between them, semantically and/or syntactically?

Answer (score 1):

> Amazon is beloved by investors.
>
> Amazon is loved by investors.

You can use either "loved" or "beloved" in the sentence, without any difference in meaning.  But "beloved" is stronger than "loved"; "beloved" means "loved" very much.

Besides, "loved" is the past participle of love and the sentence is in the passive. On the other hand, "beloved" is an adjective; you can use the preposition "of" or "by" after it.

Comment: Is it possible to say "Amazon is very loved by investors"? If so, can't "loved" be also an adjective?

Comment: Yes, you can say Amazon is very much loved by investors; loved is a verb here.

Comment: Loved as an adjective can be used, for example, Amazon is a loved company of investors.

Comment: Is only "Amazon is very much loved by investors" possible, but not "Amazon is very loved by investors"?

Comment: Yes, we should use very much, not very.  You can use very before an adjective such as he's very upset.

Comment: Thank. I've searched "very loved by" in Google News. Are these then all incorrect English?: http://bit.ly/29rzXMK

Comment: @JK2,  Please see the use of very in the following link.

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/very

Comment: Thanks for the link. After carefully reading the link, my question is, how do you know for sure that "loved" in "Amazon is loved by investors" is not an adjective but a past participle (verb)? 'Cause if it can be an adjective in that sentence, then it can certainly be modified by "very" alone without "much". And you say, it cannot be modified by "very" alone, which means that you're sure that the "loved" cannot be an adjective in this sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Either

> Amazon is *beloved* by investors.
>   Amazon is *loved* by investors.

can be used and it would easily be understood that investors have a positive affection for the stock.

However, "beloved" is a stronger and more intense feeling of love that may border on "worship".

> She lost her *beloved* cat of 19 years.
>
> Amazon is *beloved* by investors.
>   *Amazon is worshipped by investors*

there are some who would not disagree with this statement.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary.com gives the following etymology for the English prefix *be-*, which can illustrate how the meaning is modified.

> word-forming element with a wide range of meaning: *completely; to make, cause seem; to provide with; at, on, to, for*
>
> from Old English be- "on all sides" (also used to make transitive
>   verbs and as a privative or intensive prefix)

In the case of *belove* it's probably best to say it's an "intensive" prefix, so it means "to love very much."

*Belove* though is not used anymore as a verb with a subject/object by itself (very rarely, if at all), but the past-participle-as-adjective use lives on.